# How can I sharpen pencils without a dedicated sharpener?

Tags: substitute-tool, stationery

There have been times when I was without a sharpener, and a pencil I was using became dull. I tried using my knife, but that seems to break the point. Am I doing it wrong, or is there a better way to get out of the problem? I was using pencils specifically because they're erasable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're doing it wrong.  Most artists I know use a pen knife to sharpen pencils.  The trick is to only bear down on the wooden part and cut along a shallow angle.  To finish the graphite point, use extremely light pressure.

[How to sharpen a pencil with a knife](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IGtdKZfCQac)

Comment: If you need to sharpen the graphite itself, you're using the wrong pencil: find a finer one.

Comment: FYI, Most artists I know use a pencil sharpener and for mechanical pencils (used by draughtsmen in days of yore) a rotary lead "pointer" was handy when not using a sandpaper scrap or a specially made sanding block. The pen knife was/is still used to cut the ends of flight feathers (quills) into quill pens.

Answer (score 6):

I don't carry a knife. I have often been drawing/sketching while in a park or on a city bench near a curbside and I have found the rough pavement and/or concrete on the ground works well in a pinch (on those occasions when I don't have my sharpener with me). You're not going to get a perfect sharp tip, but it will remove the wood enough to get more of the graphite out and available for continued use.

Similar, if you are near a brick building, you can use the mortar in the joints between the bricks as it provides a nice channel for the pencil to shimmy through.

Answer (score 4):

I like to use an emory board to sharpen or shape a drawing pencil. I don't expect it would work well for starting from scratch ; ) with a new pencil, but works well otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

It is actually easier to sharpen a pencil with a [box-cutter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility_knife#/media/File:Box-cutter.jpg) than a pocket knife (it is sharper, so you need to apply less pressure, which allows you to have more control over what and how you are cutting). Because using a knife for sharpening takes some practice, it may be a good idea to use a box-cutter until you get used to it.

Another option is to use a mechanical pencil instead - no need for sharpening.

Answer (score 1):

A rough grit sandpaper works in a pinch, as do nail files and other wood or steel files.

Comment: Nail files don't work.

Comment: it does take time, and a polishing file would be worthless. If I am using sandpaper to sharpen a pencil I prefer the sandpaper be on a belt sander.